# Adding reviewers to pull request using github-java sdk

Tags: java, github-api

I am trying to use `https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core` to create a pull request, but I can't find a way to add reviews to the pull request. The V3 Github API supports adding reviewers as mentioned here, https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#create-a-review-request. I am trying to create the pull request as follows.

```
private void createPullRequest(
        String repositoryName,
        String repositoryOwner,
        String pullRequestTitle,
        String pullRequestBody,
        String branchSource,
        String branchDestination
) throws IOException {

    logger.info("starting to create pull request");

    var gitHubClient = new GitHubClient();
    gitHubClient.setCredentials("x", "y");
    var repositoryService = new RepositoryService(gitHubClient);
    var repository = repositoryService.getRepository(repositoryOwner, repositoryName);

    var pullRequestService = new PullRequestService(gitHubClient);
    var pullRequest = new PullRequest();
    pullRequest.setTitle(pullRequestTitle);
    pullRequest.setBody(pullRequestBody);

    pullRequest.setHead(
            new PullRequestMarker().setRef(branchSource).setLabel(branchSource)
    );

    pullRequest.setBase(
            new PullRequestMarker().setRef(branchDestination).setLabel(branchDestination)
    );

    logger.info("Finally starting to push PR");

    pullRequestService.createPullRequest(repository, pullRequest);

    logger.info("PR should be created now");
}
```

From the documentation it says, it supports 100% of Github V3 API. But I am unable to find any reference in code & online for adding reviewers.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm searching for the same. It seems its not supported.